# parsley.js remote validation with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I use parsley.js and I would like to integrate a validation, which checks on the server-site if the entered value is already in the database.
On the server site I need more information than just the value of the input. So I need to submit more parameters (in this simplified example "obj-id" and "site-id"=.

I don't know which approach to choose. I think a custom remote validation could be the right way.

I also don't know how the response of the server has to look like.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>parsley.js Remote Validation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>parsley.js Remote Validation</h1>
    <label for="name" class="form-label sr-only">Name</label>
    <input id="name" class="form-control" name="tag[name]" required 
           data-obj-id="200" data-site-id="100"
           data-parsley-remote
           data-parsley-remote-validator='check-dupliate'
           data-parsley-required-message="Please enter a name!"
     >
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-save">Save</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
$('#name').parsley();

$(document).on('click', '.btn-save', function()
{
    if ($('#name').parsley().validate() === true)
    {
    console.log('do stuff');
  }
});

window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator('check-dupliate', function (xhr)
{
    $element = this.$element;
  console.log($element.data('obj-id'));
  console.log($element.data('site-id'));
  return 404 === xhr.status;
}, document.URL, );
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Phantomias/3xmqu840/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#remote), you can use the attribute `data-parsley-remote-options` to pass extra settings to your validator, in order to give more context to your API endpoint, without making a custom validator.

According to your snippet, it would like something like that

```js
<input
 id="name"
 class="form-control"
 name="tag[name]"
 required 
 data-parsley-remote-options='{"type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp", "data":{"obj_id":"200","site_id":"100"}}'
 data-parsley-remote
 data-parsley-required-message="Please enter a name!"
/>
```

This object `{"type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp", "data":{"obj_id":"200","site_id":"100"}}` will make a `POST` call and will send `data` along with the value of your field.

Here is your [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9tmexsh/) with `POST` call and 3 values sent as form post values to the endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried ```data-parsley-remote-options``` before, but it never worked. At the end it was really a stupid error. This works: ```data-parsley-remote-options='{"type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp", "data":{"obj_id":"200","site_id":"100"}}'``` , this does not: ```data-parsley-remote-options="{"type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp", "data":{"obj_id":"200","site_id":"100"}}"``` (double quotation marks vs. single quotation marks).